# Microsoft Sync Framework 4.0 how to handle foreign key constraints on a sync

Tags: html, microsoft-sync-framework

I am building an offline/online web app for the ipad. For synchronization I am using the Microsoft Sync Framework 4.0. A problem I am running into is with foreign key relationships in the sync process. For example:

I have a schedule table and and interview table. Interviews have a foreign key relationship with schedule. When I add a schedule and an Interview and then try to sync, the new interview sometimes gets added before the new schedule which causes a conflict because the foreign key that the interview is referencing does not exist yet.

I have read about sync groups but I am not sure how to implement them or if they are the answer to my problem.

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I looked further at the Sync Service Utility UI, in step 4 of the process of generating your configuration file you can actually specify the order of the tables. I think this will solve my problems with foreign keys. Thanks for pointing me in the right direction JuneT.

Comment: Note that Inserts should go parent-to-child but Deletes should go child-to-parent. (with respect to their fk relationship)

Comment: Oh: For DbServerSyncProvider, Microsoft.Sync reverses the table order deletes in DbServerSyncProvider.ApplyChangesInternal.

Comment: Microsoft.Sync DbServerSyncProvider ApplyChanges Ordering: Deletes then Inserts then Updates. It seems to me that this ordering should instead be Inserts then Updates then Deletes. What if you insert then delete the same row? (this might be filtered out by the enumerate-changes logic on the client provider side) What if you do an update which removes the last reference to the parent then delete the parent? The sync fails on a FK violation.

Answer (score 2):

check that when you provisioned the scope, you added the parent table (schedule) before the child table (interview)

Comment: How do I ensure that I actually am adding the parent table first. I am using the Sync Service Utility UI and I have seen nothing about ordering the tables durring provisioning. Do I actually need to edit the config xml?